# Which C variable type to use

Tags: c, types

I have account numbers that are in the same form as SS numbers, for example, 123-12-1234  What C variable type should be sued to store these?  Can a primitive type hold such 'numbers'? A brief explanation would be great too! Thanks

Comment: Consider it was written as `123121234`, how could that value be stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you want to do with these numbers? You may want to store them as a string if you want to display them. You may want to store it as 3 ints if each section means something and you will be comparing them. You may want to store it as 1 int and handle formatting when you display it if you will be doing a lot of comparisons or sorting.

Comment: So if I assigned this to some sort of int, it would still be able to handle it, it just wouldn't retain the dashes? I am wondering if there is some sort of quirk in C that allows me to handle these nicely.  No particular use specified.

Comment: It all depends on your input. No matter what if you are storing it in an int you need to strip out the dashes. Where you do that, it depends. But you can not do int x = 123-45-6789. Well you could, but you would get a bunch of subtraction and no dashes. If you had a database, you could strip the dashes in one pass. If you are getting user input, you could ask them to enter it without the dashes. All depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

If the account numbers have a fixed number of characters, a fixed array of characters like `char[11]` might be appropriate; otherwise go for the traditional null-terminated char-array (a.k.a. "C string").

Answer (score 0):

if you reflect over it you'll see that char* / [long] int will fit your needs. depending on your needs

Answer (score 0):

I think using it as a char * would be better. Doing this, you can also implement 2-level hashing to search for account numbers.